# how to run papi rapl on intel atom

Tags: software-installation, intel

I am trying to run the rapl of papi-5.3.2 on intel atom (Intel(R) Atom(TM) CPU  C2758  @ 2.40GHz).
When I try to run make file in the rapl, msg I get is

"make: *** No rule to make target `-L../../..', needed by`rapl_basic'.  Stop."

Can you please guide me how to run the rapl on atom?
I am using ubuntu version 13.10.

Comment: Could you give the command that generated that error above? Are you just running `make`?

Comment: I have downloaded the papi-5.3.2. Then I run ./configure --with-component=rapl. then I have run the make command but rapl_basic, rapl_busy executable files were not generated so I cd components/rapl and type again make command there I got the above error.

Comment: Please *[edit]* your question with that information. What version of Ubuntu are you running?

Comment: This question is off topic as non-reproducible because it has been abandoned by the author for 6 years.

Answer (score 0):

you dont need to implement difficult compilations to install `papi` in Ubuntu. It is in the [Official Ubuntu Repository](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=papi&searchon=names&suite=trusty&section=all).

You can install it as:

```
sudo apt-get install libpapi5.3
```

Comment: BY the above command I am getting this message:                   E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'libpapi5.3'

Comment: what is your ubuntu version?

Comment: ubuntu version 13.10

Comment: Sorry. Ubuntu 13.10 isnt officially supported. You need to proceeded with compilation.